# Error While Convert SQL query to LINQ With LINQER

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I can convert this query with linqer.

```
select * 
from v#gharardad 
inner join (select FK#GharardadeAsli, Max(PK#Shenase) as PK#Shenase, Max(TarikheSabt) as TarikheSabt 
            from TBL#Gharardad 
            where FK#GharardadeAsli is not null 
            group by FK#GharardadeAsli
            ) sub on sub.PK#Shenase = v#gharardad.[Shenase]
```

Error: >SQL cannot be converted to LINQ: Field [sub].[PK#Shenase] not found in the current Data Context.

If there is no way to pass this error so can you tell me its LINQ equal?

Comment: can you tell me what is # mean in "v#gharardad"?

Comment: Maybe a little off-topic, but why would you ever include '#' in a table or view name?

Comment: Yes i know about it but I intend to help you myself

Comment: But it is really bad.you better to don't use # because the ef will convert it to _ and nHydrate will cause error with #.i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#` char seems to be translated to `_` by the LINQ designer.

Try to create temporary views where you replace all `#` with `_`. Then run the query in Linqer again and it will probably work.

Comment: linqer can't recognize [sub] your answer is really wrong.but thanks good effort

Comment: As you see it is not a linq query , it is sql query

Comment: Sometimes i think i can use unicode character in my variable name so why c# don't let me to use # character in the variable name